# SAS BI Dashboard Feedback - What is your experience?

Tags: report, sas, business-intelligence, dashboard

**Backgroup:** 
We are looking at SAS BI Dashboard. We have currently implemented almost all of SAS's other applications (with the exception of Enterprise Miner). Other technologies online include Business Objects, some custom reporting stuff, and Project R.

**The Question:**
What feedback do you have with:

1. implementing SAS BI Dashboard
2. building dashboards and reports in BI
3. linking BI with other technologies, databases, and SAS datasets

Comment: Can you turn this into one or more question(s) can have a single answer, rather than a potentially-infinite number of anecdotal replies? Perhaps take each of your list items, describe what you're trying to do and ask for help accomplishing it...

Comment: At the very list this should have been a community wiki, but I'm bored to tears by the subject matter anyway.

Comment: You aren't even SAS users. Don't comment on the subject when you have no expertise with the technology.

Comment: AFHood: WTF does expertise in SAS have to do with being able to recognize a bad question? I commented because i wanted to help you out - if you didn't notice, you're getting no replies and collecting down-votes, because you're soliciting general discussion instead of specific answers. Meh. Your loss...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it a lot myself but a friend has and even wrote a paper for the last SAS Global Forum that is on this very topic that might have some useful info for you.

http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/044-2009.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Due to licensing costs and difficulty of implementation (you have to use a specific -- not the most recent -- version of WebLogic, etc.), we COMPLETELY dumped the BI Dashboard and replaced it with LifeRay (open source portal).

SAS analytics, graphics, etc. are surfaced through weblogic calls to the SAS Stored Process server.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the new SAS "BI Dashboard" offering, but I've done a lot of dashboards using SAS/Graph, such as the following (included here, along with the SAS code used to create them):

http://robslink.com/SAS/dashboards/aaaindex.htm

Doing dashboards this way, you can create standalone web output (like the ones above), either interactively or from a batch job, or you can generate them on-the-fly when you click on a web page via SAS/Intrnet or a BI Stored Process.  The output can be viewed in a simple web browser, and/or you can display the URL output in a Portal (be it the SAS Portal, SAS Web Report Studio, or other).